# How to assemble different serializers to a Json response in Django RFW?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

This is my serializers.py,

```
class MalbSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = malb
        fields = ('zoning', 'zoningdesc', )

class MasrSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = masr
        fields = ('solddate', 'soldprice',  )

class MataSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = mata
        fields = ('assessyear', 'landvalue', )

class TotalSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    LandBuilding = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    SalesRecord = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    TaxAssessment = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_LandBuilding(self, number):

        queryset_lb = malb.objects.filter(maid=number)
        serializer = MalbSerializer(queryset_lb, many=True)
        return serializer.data

    def get_SalesRecord(self, number):

        queryset_sr = masr.objects.filter(maid=number)
        serializer = MasrSerializer(queryset_sr, many=True)
        return serializer.data


    def get_TaxAssessment(self, number):

        queryset_ta = mata.objects.filter(maid=number)
        serializer = MataSerializer(queryset_ta, many=True)
        return serializer.data

    class Meta:

        fields = ('LandBuilding', 'SalesRecord', 'TaxAssessment', )
```

I want to assemble these three serializers to one serializer in TotalSerializer, But it has an error:

```
Class TotalSerializer missing "Meta.model" attribute
```

I don't know add which models to here, because I have already add models in MalbSerializer, MasrSerializer, MataSerializer.

So How can I do to show MalbSerializer, MasrSerializer, MataSerializer together in TotalSerializer?

Comment: Where is your `MaidExtraSerializer ` serializer?

Comment: @MaidExtraSerializer is TotalSerializer... I change name and forget to correct it in the problem, my falut

Answer (score 0):

`TotalSerializer` should subclass `serializers.Serializer`, not `serializers.ModelSerializer`.